# How to fix c# code "IndexOutOfRangeException" was unhandled

Tags: c#

Hi i am writing a code to randomize everyday in 12 months to see if it rains and how much it rain. however when i want to store it in a 2D array it happens to have an error and i am so stuck with that, how can i fix it?
I have declare these at the start of the program

```
static int[] daysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
```

This is the method having problem

```
 static void MakeItRain(int[][] rainfall)
    {
        Random Rainfall = new Random(10);
        Random RainOrNot = new Random(10);



        for (int j = 0; j < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (daysInMonth[j]); i++)
            {
                if (RainOrNot.Next(1, 5) == 1)

                {
                    rainfall[i][j] = Rainfall.Next(1, 28);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would suggest binding `int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = daysInMonth.length - 1` to navigate any issues coming from the hardcode.

Comment: How did you initialize rainfall? Have you initialize each month?

Comment: but  MONTHS_IN_YEAR should have different value from daysInMonth as they refer to different things

Comment: @Martheen
<pre>int[][] rainfall = new int[MONTHS_IN_YEAR][];

Comment: when you initialize rainfall with `new int[MONTHS_IN_YEAR][]` shouldnt you fill it with `rainfall[j][i]` ? because `j` is counting  `MONTHS_IN_YEAR` not `i`. currently `rainfall[i][j]` is invalid.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary i have tried both ways and it turns out to be having the same problems

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize this jagged array first by `MONTHS_IN_YEAR` then you must fill it with correct index

```
 int[][] rainfall = new int[MONTHS_IN_YEAR][];
```

Have you noticed? the second array is not initialized. that means you cant do forexample

```
rainfall[0][0] = something;
```

you have to first initialize second array

```
rainfall[0] = new int[6];
rainfall[0][0] = something;
```

now your code should look like this

```
 static void MakeItRain(int[][] rainfall)
    {
        Random Rainfall = new Random(10);
        Random RainOrNot = new Random(10);

        for (int j = 0; j < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; j++)
        {
            rainfall[j] = new int[daysInMonth[j]]; // initialize second array

            for (int i = 0; i < (daysInMonth[j]); i++)
            {
                if (RainOrNot.Next(1, 5) == 1)
                {
                    rainfall[j][i] = Rainfall.Next(1, 28);
                }
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! it seems working for me! but when i try to run it it comes out an error in ""rainfall[j][] = new int[daysInMonth[j]];"" where there is a  "Syntax error; value expected" at the second bracket of rainfall

Comment: @K.Leung look at edit. sorry for typo. it should be `rainfall[j] = new int[daysInMonth[j]];`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code successfully, but got an IndexOutOfRangeException when the 'rainfall' array passed to the MakeItRain method was too small for the iterations inside the method to navigate through it.

This ran successfully:

```
public class Program
{
    static int[] daysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] rain = new int[31, MONTHS_IN_YEAR];
        MakeItRain(rain);
    }

    static void MakeItRain(int[,] rainfall)
    {
        Random Rainfall = new Random(10);
        Random RainOrNot = new Random(10);

        for (int j = 0; j < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (daysInMonth[j]); i++)
            {
                if (RainOrNot.Next(1, 5) == 1)
                {
                    rainfall[i,j] = Rainfall.Next(1, 28);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for helping! this works with me too but the problem is i want to do it in a way that each column of the array have different length. just like when i am doing Jan, the array has 31 and when i am doing Feb, i have 28
how can i do this?
btw, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: so that the output will be like Rain[1][14] = 20 meaning that it rains 20mm of rain in 14th Jan

Comment: @K.Leung First of all, no problem! :) I'm afraid you can't do that with Arrays. Have you tried it with Collections? They are more flexible in terms of number of elements initialized, as well as removing and adding elements dynamically.

Comment: i haven't learn about that...is there another way of doing it? as the question really struggled me...the question need us to Output for each month the rainfall amount for any day on which rainfall occurred

Comment: @K.Leung does the question actually ask you to use arrays? You can easily do it with collections. Let me code it and show you.